# Retrieve data stored in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Hi my mapping is as follows,

```
    "mappings":{
        "classes": {
            "properties": {
                "class": {"type": "integer"},
                "students": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "roll_id": {"type": "integer"},
                    "student_name": {
                        "type": "nested",
                          "properties": {
                            "first_name": { "type": "text" },
                            "last_name":  { "type": "text" }
                          }
                        },
                        "performance_grade": {"type": "text"},
                        "location": {"type": "text"},
                        "contact_number": {"type": "integer"},
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to search three cases:

1. find students in class 11 whose performance grade is D
2. find students in class 11 whose  performance grade is D and location
   is 'New York'
3. find all students whose first name is 'Tim'.

as you can see i want to filter students  is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is possible

- If you filter exactly by location you should use type keyword, or using phrase query
- performance_grade you can using numerical type for range filter
- Contact number should using keyword